# rails routes gives an error - wrong controller seems to be called

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I can't figure out what's wrong with my routes. I'm very new to rails (and programming) so it could be something very simple.

Clicking on my home page gives the following error -

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"bets"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

This is my routes.rb

```
 root :to => 'pages#home'
 resources :bets
 resources :bettingevents
 get  '/bet' => 'bets#index'
 get  '/bettingevent' => 'bettingevents#index'
```

The show function in my bets controller has

```
  def show

  redirect_to(bets_path)
  end
```

`localhost:3000/bets` is fine, with create, update, delete, edit routes working correctly. My pages controller has been working perfectly till I added the bets routes.

If i remove `resources :bets` the homepage works all right, but none of the bets routes work.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: In your routes creating `resource :bets` would add CRUD, 7 diff, routes. So you dont have to declare again with `get '/bet' => 'bets#index'` same with bettingevent

Comment: @Uday she might have done this bcoz she would have wanted define the named routes for those two actions

Comment: @AnganaJacob so u have a problem with your home page so what is inside  your home controller

Comment: @Viren, yeah that can be a possiblity too.

Comment: just as rails tries to help you: "Try running rake routes for more information on available routes." so go to your console and execute ```rake routes```

Comment: @Viren, thanks for pointing it out. As I mentioned, if I remove in 'get /bet' in routes.rb, I got the routing error mentioned above. I noticed I had a link to the bets index page through 'bet_path' on my home page and it was this path that was causing the error. I changed it to 'bets_path', removed the 'get /bet' and 'get /bettingevent' as you suggested and everything works fine. I will close this question now.